# How to call parent ViewModel method when child view is closed mvvm

Tags: c#, winforms, mvvm, devexpress

I have two forms are **parent form** and **child form**. In parent form contain **Treelist items** and when I click on each item, other form (child form) will display for rename focus **treelist item**. After rename it and click on save button in child form that child form is close automatically when save is completed and update what I have been changed in parent form also.
I want to **reload data** in parent form when child form is closed by calling method "Reload" in parent view model.
I try to bind child form closing event with command in parent form but it's not working.

```
_fluent.WithEvent(ChildForm, "FormClosing").EventToCommand(x => x.Reload());
```

Comment: Yes its fine to tell us what you want to do, but you need to put some more effort in. how are you plumbing this all together, are you using some mvvm framework, who is creating the Viewmodels and Views... I'm voting to close until you are more specific

Comment: I already updated my question

Answer (score 1):

It is likely that you are using DevExpress MVVM WinForms Framework. If so, generally, to communicate between different view models, you can use [Messenger](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/113982/Build-an-Application/WinForms-MVVM/Concepts/Layer-Communication-Messenger). Thus, once your parent view model receives a corresponding message from your view model, you can call the Reload method.

Comment: Are there any other ways to avoid using Messenger? It's not good implementation, there is a problem if many view-model using messenger  but implement on difference part.

Comment: There should not be a problem with using Messenger and multiple view models since Messenger supports tokens specially designed for such purposes.